# How can I set the entire background or body of a page to execute a function when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to make the entire background/body of a web project I am working on to execute a function.  Would it be possible to set the body to be a link or button?

I also want this to remain in the background, as I have another link in the front of the page.

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="">Test link in front of page</a>
<style>
body{
background-color:aqua;
}
a{
color:white;
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
transform: translateY(-50%); 
width: 100%; 
text-align: center;
margin: 0; 
}
</body>
</html>
```

For a visual example, I made a code snippet.  My goal is to make that aqua background a link/button (that will execute a JS function), but let the white link remain in the front as a separate link to a website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might add a clickhandler to the document:

```
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log("hello"));
```

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log("hello"));
```

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="">Test link in front of page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding:**
I believe you want a function to run each time the user clicks the body of the HTML document

**Suggestion:**
You can add an event listener to the document, when it is a click then call the function you want. If it has to specifically be the body and not an overlapping element then you can perform a test within the function to see if the element clicked was the one you had anticipated for. such as e.target.tagName == "BODY"

**Running Example:**

```js
function myFunctionCall(e){
  if (e.target.tagName == "HTML" || e.target.tagName == "BODY"){
    alert ("HEYY YOU CLICKED ME ");
  }
}
document.addEventListener("click", myFunctionCall, false);
```

```css
body{
  background-color:aqua;
}

a{
  color:white;
  margin: 0; 
  position: absolute; 
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%; 
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  width: 100%

  
}
```

```html
<body >
  <a href="" >Test link in front of page</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to put your body in front of the link ?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    *
    {
      box-sizing: border-box;
     }
    body
    {
      background-color:aqua;
    }
    a.back
    {
      color:white;
      position: absolute; 
      top: 50%; 
      transform: translateY(-50%); 
      width: 100%; 
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0; 
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    p
    {
      width: 50%;
      height: 250px;
      margin: 1% auto;
      padding: 25% 2%;
      background-color: rgba(12, 12, 12, .4);
      text-align: center;
      color: red;
      border-radius: .2rem;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#!" class="back">Test link in front of page</a>
  <p>
  Do you mean something like this ? 
  <br/>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```